# Youtube Flash / HTML5 Player

Tags: javascript, html, actionscript-3, youtube

I am working on a small project that envolves geting the time to wich a user skips to when playing a video.

I am using the javascript part of the API to play the video, pause and so on, but I cannot seem to understand how to get the time that the user skips to. I know I can seekTo on my own... But there seems to be no corresponding event for when the user does this

I am trying to find the event that fires when the user skips to a certain time...

From YT API I see they do not have such an event (in javascript... I wouldn't like to create my own custom player based on HTML5 and/or AS3).

Comment: COde updated, please check it

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there isn't a real way to do it, but probably you can "intercept" it and understand it, it won't take long:

In [this page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo) you can see all the featurea available for the api. You can do it in 2 way:

1. checking and confronting the time of the video with a counter continuously (probably a bad idea).
2. Intercepting the player state:
   There are [5 state](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#onStateChange) for the player, when the player cursor is moved:
   -if the player was playing, the state go from 1 to 2 and then from 2 to 1.
   -if the players was paused, nothing happens to his state.
   Considering that you can intercept the player state you can easily get the current time when the player is paused and then, confront it with the current time when the user restart play. In each of the 2 case, you should be able to know if the user moved or not the cursor. I don't know well this api so I don't know if some other state of the player can mean something important for your question. I think this way, if isn't complete, it's a good start from where begin developing your idea.

### UPDATE

**HERE IS THE CODE EXAMPLE TESTED + [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/HJRQp/2/)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <body>
    <!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
    <div id="player"></div>

    <script>
var doing = -1;
var timenow=0;
var timeold=0;
var flag=0;
      // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
      var tag = document.createElement('script');

      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
      //    after the API code downloads.
      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
      }

      // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
      function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
      }

      // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
      //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
      //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
      var done = false;
      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if(flag==1){
        flag=0;
        timenow=timeold;
    }else{
        if((doing==-1)&&(event['data']==1)){//start play
            doing=1;
        }
        if((doing==1)&&(event['data']==2)){//from play to pause
            timeold=player.getCurrentTime();
            timeold=timeold;
            doing=2;
            console.log('go pause at:'+timeold);
        }
        if((doing==2)&&(event['data']==1)){//from pause to play
            timenow=player.getCurrentTime();
            console.log('go play at:'+timenow);
            if(timenow>timeold){
                alert('are you kidding me?! You switched from '+timeold+' to '+timenow+'!');
                player.seekTo(timeold);
                flag=1;
            }else{
                timeold=timenow;
            }
        }
            if(event['data']==5 || event['data']<1){//stopped or ended
                    doing=-1;
                    timeold=0;
                    timenew=0;
            }
    }
      }
      function stopVideo() {
        player.stopVideo();
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```